# Installing an old version of helmfile which is not in brew repo

Tags: kubernetes, helmfile

I need to install certain version of helmfile (0.144) but cannot find that version in brew repo. Only latest is available. Tried brew search, but it only shows `helmfile`

Can I manually install https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases/tag/v0.144.0 and create working symlinks?

Comment: The end of the Homebrew [Formulae Versions](https://docs.brew.sh/Versions) documentation page discusses using `brew extract` to get an old version of a specific formula.  I was using this for a while when the project I was working on hadn't taken the renamings in Helmfile 0.150.  But this isn't quite a programming-related question, and assuming this is on a MacOS host, another site like [apple.se] might be a better place to ask about operating Homebrew.